# Matlab - Find Coordinates between a straight line and a perimeter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, intersection

I segmented a mouse and get its image-properties using `bwlabel`. Thereby I have access to the position of the centroid and the orientation of the mouse. I also get the perimeter of the mouse using `bwperim`.

I want to find the two points of the straight line passing through the centroid and having the same direction than the orientation of the mouse cutting the perimeter.

I find the equation of the straight line using that code :

```
% E is a 2*2 matrix containing the coordinates of the centroid and the
% coordinates of the point which belong to the straight line and making 
% the right angle given by the orientation
coeffs = polyfit(E(:,1),E(:,2),1);
% Create the equation of the straight line
x = 1:width;
yfit = coeffs(1)*x+coeffs(2);
% Make sure there are only int values.
yfit = uint16(yfit);
```

I convert my values to `uint16` because i want to fill a new matrix that I will compare with the matrix containing the perimeter. Here is what I do then :

```
% Create a matrix of zeros and set to 1 all the pixels which belong to the
% straight line 
k = 1;
temp = false;
m = false(size(iPerim));
while temp~=true
    temp = false;
    if yfit(k) > 0
        m(yfit(k),k)=1;
        temp = true;
    end
    k = k+1;
end
[t,p] = ind2sub(size(m), find(m==1));
minM = [min(p),min(t)];
% complete the straight line to don't have little holes
x = linspace(minM(1),D(1),width);
y = coeffs(1)*x+coeffs(2);
idx = sub2ind(size(m),round(y),round(x));
m(idx) = 1;
```

Then I compare m with iPerim which is the matrix containing my perimeter:

```
% Compare the matrix of the perimeter and the matrix of the straight line
% and find the two points in common. It is the points where the straight
% line cut the perimeter
p = m & iPerim;
% Extract thoses coordinates 
[coordsY,coordsX] = ind2sub(size(p), find(p==1));
```

Well I am a new user of Matlab so I think this is not a elegant solution but there is the result:

**Matrix m**

[image: matrix m]

**Perimeter in which I plot yfit**

[image: Perimeter where I plot yfit]

As you can see the algorithm detects only one point and not the second one (the yellow spot)... I figure why but I can't find the solution. It is because the line straight is cutting the perimeter through a diagonal but there are not coordinates in common...

Somebody has a solution to my problem ? And of course I am taking any advises conerning my code :)

Thank you very much !

Edit: If there is a easier solution I take it obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the coordinate of the point where the mouse-perimeter and the line cross are `E(2,:)`, then the position of this point in the line is where the distance is minimal. E.g. like:

```
[xLine, yLine] = find(m);    % x,y positions of the line
dX = abs(xline-E(2,1))       % x-distance to x-coordinate of direction-point
dY = abs(yLine-E(2,2))       % y-distance to y-coordinate of direction-point
distP =  sqrt(dX.^2+dY.^2)   % distance of line-points to directon-point
[~,indMin] = min(distP);     % index of line-point which has the minimum distance
xPoint = xLine(indMin(1)); 
yPoint = yLine(indMin(1));
```

The `abs` and `sqrt`functions are not necessary here for finding the right point, only for the correct intermediate values...

From the Matlab Documentation about [ind2sub](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

> For matrices, [I,J] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A>5)) returns the same values as [I,J] = find(A>5).